# replace number and symbol with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Does anyone know how can I replace the number and symbol (excluding dash and single quote)?

Example:
if I have a string "ABDHN'S-J34H@#$";
How can I replace the number and symbol to empty and return me value "ABDHN'S-JH" ?

I have the following code to replay all the char and symbol to empty and only return me number

```
$(".test").keyup(function (e) {
    orgValue = $(".test").val();
    if (e.which != 37 && e.which != 39 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 46) {
        newValue = orgValue.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
        $(".test").val(newValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow only letters, dash and single quotes, like this:

```
newValue = orgValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z'-]/g, "");
```

Anything else will be replaced by "".

Comment: You mean - `newValue = orgValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z'-.]/g,"");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
string.replace(/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/, '')
```

The caret ^ inside a character class [] will negate the match. This regex will convert all characters other than `a-z`, `A-Z`, `single quote` and `hyphen` to empty

Answer (score 1):

You could replace symbols by skipping them through keycode value on the keyboard.

Link for keycode values for reglar keyboard:
http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

```
     $("#your control").bind("keydown keyup", doItPlease);

function doItPlease(e)
 {
// First 2 Ifs are for numbers for num pad and alpha pad numbers
 if (e.which < 106 && e.which > 95)
 {
    return false; // replace your values or return false
 } 
 else if (e.which < 58 && e.which > 47) 
{
    // replace your values or return false
} else {
    var mycharacters = [8, 9, 33, 34, 35 // get your coders from above link];
    for (var i = 0; i < mycharacters.length; i++) {
        if (e.which == mycharacters[i]) {
             // replace your characters or just
             // return false; will cancel the key down and wont even allow it
        }
      e.preventDefault();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
"ABDHN'S-J34H@#$".replace(/[^\-'\w]/g, '')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
"ABDHN'S-J34H@#$".replace(/[0-9]|[\'@#$]/g, "");
```